# a better way to return true or int from function

Tags: php, google-maps

I have a `Address_Finder` class with a method `get_address( $ordinal, $postcode )` that uses a mixture of google map API and a database to get a full address

`get_address` finds the address details: lat, lng, street_name, etc from a `$ordinal` and `$postcode` and once called, it sets the instance's address variables to the results.

If it finds the address successfully, it sets the internal data to the results and returns `true`.

However if the address already exists in the database, it returns the `address_id` of the address in the database.

So obviously the return values for the function are either true, or a standard php integer type.

We could do something like this:

```
$address = new Address_Finder();
$address_id = $address -> get_address( "2", "NG8 5NW" );

if ( $address_id ){
    $address_id = $address -> save(); // saves the address to the database
}
```

Now the `if ( $address_id )` will evaluate true if get_address returns true, or if it returns the `$address_id` 1.

This could be solved by doing:

```
if ( $address_id === true ){
    // save returns the address ID of the last inserted address
    $address_id = $address -> save();
}
```

However I was wondering if there way a better way to do this?

Like... I was hoping to release my Address_Finder class as an API on my blog so other programmers out there can use it.

So by 'better way', I'm thinking in terms of how programmers will use my API

Comment: You are not telling us the most important part: why and how does the caller care if the address already exists in the database and what its id is? Are there other proposed API methods related to `getAddress`? API design cannot be done in isolated bits.

Comment: If two different return values are confusing, don't return different values. :)

Comment: Sorry, say the user wants to use the address id as a foreign key in another database table... Then they would use the API to find the full address from the postcode, and get the ID regardless of whether it came from the database or google API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return an array instead of a simple value:

```
{
 'success':true||false,  //boolean indicating if get_address was successfull
 'id':     int||null     //id returned by get_address when successfull
}
```